# How to set permissions to allow Google Sheets to use an Apps Script to query my Contacts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-contacts-api, custom-function

I have a Google Sheet that I want to check if an email address already exists in my list of Contacts.

I wrote an Apps Script with this function

```
function isAContact(email) {
    if (null != ContactsApp.getContact(email)) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I run this function directly in Google Apps Scripts it works fine, after it asked for permission on the first run.

When I call this function in Google Sheets

```
=isAContact(H4) // H4 is a cell with an email address
```

it complains that the **permission to call getContact() is denied**.

How can I allow this spreadsheet to use the Contacts Api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom functions cannot do anything that requires permissions:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

Work arounds include:
Timed trigger pulling in your contacts list every 5 min to a hidden sheet and setting up your comparison against that.

changing your function to work on the active range or a preset range when triggered from a custom menu:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getUi()

Comment: Hm I missed that part of the documentation :(
Thanks for the hint.

I'll go with your work around suggestion. Thanks